# Manifest Merger Failed when allow backup is made false

Tags: android, android-manifest

In the android manifest file,when i make android:allowBackup="true" to android:allowBackup="false" then it through me the error of maifest murger failed.

My Manifest File is :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.goturbo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/trucks"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="android:icon"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">    

       <activity
            android:name="com.goturbo.FragmentContainerActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 </manifest>
```

Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

Comment: Can you share the full manifest file?

Comment: when i make  android:allowBackup="true",it's work fine

Comment: can you post the errors ?

Answer (score 6):

use        tools:replace="android:allowBackup"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In the AndroidManifest.xml file, look at the bottom and select Merged Manifest. This should help you identify where the conflict is. Sometimes it will give you the option to fix it automatically.

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV4v9.png)

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The android documentation says

> Whether to allow the application to participate in the backup and
>   restore infrastructure. If this attribute is set to false, no backup
>   or restore of the application will ever be performed, even by a
>   full-system backup that would otherwise cause all application data to
>   be saved via adb. The default value of this attribute is true.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

So if you dont mention the **allowbackup** you should be fine.

Comment: i donot want to restore the infrastructure , because when i unistall the app and reinstall the app it take my stored login data .

Comment: Why are you using allowBackup then?

Comment: i removed allowbackup, still it taking the old username and password